# Patch edited file having original and new file

Tags: file

Basically I have three files: Original file, edited (by me) file and new file (edited original file). I need to apply changes made in new file into edited file without loosing my changes. Can I do this?

Note: Running linux.

Comment: Did you try using `diff` and `patch`? I assume you have access to POSIX utilities. You did not specify what operating system are you on.

Comment: I have. But, I'm noob in linux. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a text file `original_file`

```
There is one true candidate
and it is A
```

And you have copied it to `my_file` and added a line to 
`my_file` so it looks like

```
There is one true candidate
and it is A
B would not cut it
```

Now you learned that the owner of `original_file` has also edited it and you have copied the new version to `new_file` that looks like

```
There is one true candidate
and it is C
```

Fortunately the change did not add new lines where you have added yours, so the conflict between `my_file` and `new_file` can be trivially resolved.

You create a patch using the `diff` command. The options `-Naur` are commonly used. The options specify the format of the patch file and ensure that the input files are treated as text.

```
diff -Naur original_file my_file > my_file.patch
```

Now you apply a patch to the `new_file` using `patch`

```
patch new_file my_file.patch
```

The console output would be something like

```
patching file new_file
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1 with fuzz 2.
```

This updates the `new_file` so it now looks like

```
There is one true candidate
and it is C
B would not cut it
```

By default the file `new_file.orig` is also created that is the unchanged backup copy of `new_file`.

### When it fails

Patch does good job trying to make a sensible change accounting for minor modifications. Sometimes it fails. Sometimes it produces inconsistent results.

Suppose the `new_file` was

```
There is one true candidate
and it is C
B is also good
```

Applying your patch to this file would also succeed resulting in

```
There is one true candidate
and it is C
B would not cut it
B is also good
```

This does not look consistent. It is your responsibility to check for the inconsistencies and fix them when they appear. Fortunately they do not appear often.